# Como para que al cargar nuevos datos, se coloquen abajo y no se sobreescriban?

Tags: python

Cuando cargo todos los datos me lo muestra, pero la duda es como hago que al cargar mas datos me los muestre abajo de los anteriores, adjunto foto de como esta codificado

[image: adjunto el codigo py]

```
def guardarstock():
    
    Verstock = int(input("Ingrese un 1 si quiere ver el stock o un 0 para salir: "))
    global codigoprod1, producto1, stringcantstock, stringV, opc

    while Verstock != 0:
        if Verstock != 0:
            print("|    Codigo   |     producto     | cantidad de stock   | Valor por unidad")

        archstock = open ("Stockmercaderia.txt" , "a")

        archstock.write("      ")
        archstock.write(codigoprod1)
        archstock.write("        ")
        archstock.write(producto1)
        archstock,write("   ")
        archstock.write(stringcantstock)
        archstock,write("    ")
        archstock.write(stringV)
        archstock.write("    ")
        archstock.close()   

        archstock = open ("Stockmercaderia.txt" , "r")
        print(archstock.read())
        archstock.close()

        #print(" ",codigoprod1, "    " ,producto1, "         " ,stringcantstock, "                " ,stringV)

        Verstock = int(input("Ingrese un 1 si quiere ver el stock o un 0 para salir: "))
        if Listadodepedidos == "1":
            Listadodepedidos()
        else:
            MenuPrincipal()
```

Comment: las preguntas que buscan depuracion o ayuda deben incluir el codigo, no imagenes del mismo, adicional debes mejorar la pregunta con que error te manda, cual es la entrada y cual es resultado esperado...

Comment: porque, donde te los muestra???

Comment: Me los muestras encima del anterior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imagino que lo que deseas es hacer que agregue los datos debajo de los que ya se guardaron, modifiqué un poco el codigo para que me funcionaran las variables y demas, pero se entiende, en si solo agregue el salto de linea al final de guardar los datos, asi los proximos que se inserten iran al final, `archstock.write("    \n")`

PD: revisa tu codigo, tenia unas comas donde no iban, ejemplo `archstock,write`

```
import os

ruta_script = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
codigoprod1, producto1, stringcantstock, stringV, opc= '123', 'melon', '20', '30', '89'

Verstock = int(input("Ingrese un 1 si quiere ver el stock o un 0 para salir: "))
def guardarstock():
    global codigoprod1, producto1, stringcantstock, stringV, opc

    
    
while Verstock != 0:
    if Verstock != 0:
        print("|    Codigo   |     producto     | cantidad de stock   | Valor por unidad")

    archstock = open (ruta_script+"\\Stockmercaderia.txt" , "a")

    archstock.write("      ")
    archstock.write(codigoprod1)
    archstock.write("        ")
    archstock.write(producto1)
    archstock.write("   ")
    archstock.write(stringcantstock)
    archstock.write("    ")
    archstock.write(stringV)
    archstock.write("    \n")
    archstock.close()   

    archstock = open (ruta_script+"\\Stockmercaderia.txt" , "r")
    print(archstock.read())
    archstock.close()

    #print(" ",codigoprod1, "    " ,producto1, "         " ,stringcantstock, "                " ,stringV)

    Verstock2 = int(input("Ingrese un 1 si quiere ver el stock o un 0 para salir: "))
    if Verstock2 == 1:
        codigoprod1, producto1, stringcantstock, stringV, opc= '456', 'lol', '36', '78', '99'
        guardarstock()
    else:
        guardarstock()
if Verstock==1:

    guardarstock()
```

salida:

```
Ingrese un 1 si quiere ver el stock o un 0 para salir: 1
|    Codigo   |     producto     | cantidad de stock   | Valor por unidad
      123        melon   20    30    

Ingrese un 1 si quiere ver el stock o un 0 para salir: 1
|    Codigo   |     producto     | cantidad de stock   | Valor por unidad
      123        melon   20    30    
      456        lol   36    78
```

Comment: Perfecto me funciono, ahora otra duda, si yo quiero mostrar solo lo que hat en el archivo sin tener que cargar todo otra vez cuando cierro el programa, como lo hago ?

Comment: si o si debes de cargar el archivo de alguna manera, archstock = open (ruta_script+"\\Stockmercaderia.txt" , "r")
    print(archstock.read())
    archstock.close() , puedes crear una funcion que solo lo lea e imprima y otra que agrege datos y combinarlas ambas en tu menu

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias